# upstart service giving 'chdir: command not found' error

Tags: 13.04, upstart, services

I've created an upstart conf script called watch_folder.conf that i have used successfully on a few ubuntu installs already but for some reason I'm getting an error from the following code:

```
#/etc/init/watch_folder.conf

description "watch folder service"
author      "Jonathan Topf"

start on startup

stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5


script
        chdir /home/jon/Dropbox/Render\ Farm\ 1/appleseed/bin
        exec /usr/bin/python ./watchfolder.py  ../../data/
        echo "watch_folder started"
end script
```

if I look inside /var/log/upstart/watch_folder.log i see the following

```
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
/proc/self/fd/9: line 2: chdir: command not found
...
```

Does anybody know what may cause this error, its perplexing me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`chdir`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#chdir) is its own stanza. Move it from inside the script block to outside. Here's how it should probably look:

```
description "watch folder service"
author      "Jonathan Topf"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

chdir /home/jon/Dropbox/Render\ Farm\ 1/appleseed/bin

script
        exec /usr/bin/python ./watchfolder.py  ../../data/
        echo "watch_folder started"
end script
```