# Upstart error – cd: can't cd to /home/…

Tags: users, upstart

I have the following upstart code and it gives me the following error

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/sam/Website/
```

I tried putting outside the script block as per 
[upstart service giving 'chdir: command not found' error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321867/upstart-service-giving-chdir-command-not-found-error)
but it did not work.  Anyways I'm not sure why that would make sense as per the upstart documentation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
description "SamCardCash"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid sam
setgid sam

script
  cd /home/sam/Website
  sails lift
end script

console log

respawn
```

Comment: While putting outside the `script` stanza, did you change the command from `cd` to stanza `chdir` i.e. `chdir /home/sam/Website` ?

Comment: A similar question is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154408/ .

Comment: @heemayl yes I did try and not sure why that should make a difference

Comment: @JdeBP Thank You I checked my script and it had window line ending removed and now it works! Thanks

Comment: that's because changing directory needs to go as a stanza (`chdir`) not a simple `cd` command inside upstart conf file..

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the file had Windows line endings (`CRLF` instead of `LF`). Thank you @jdeBP.

For explanation see [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154408/cant-cd-to-home-user-when-sourcing-a-script).